Playwright Async Python: "target page context or browser has been closed" Error
I am trying to crawl dynamic content from a website using Playwright in an asynchronous Python environment. However, I keep encountering the error: target page context or browser has been closed. Below is my code:
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from chatbot import init_logger
import datetime

logger = init_logger("DynamicCrawling")

class DynamicCrawler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = None
        self.context = None

    async def get_browser(self):
        if not self.browser:
            async with async_playwright() as p:
                self.browser = await p.chromium.launch()
                self.context = await self.browser.new_context()
        return self.browser, self.context

    async def get_page(self, url):
        try:
            browser, context = await self.get_browser()
            page = await context.new_page()
            await page.goto(url)
            await page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')
            dynamic_content = await page.content()
            return {
                'data': dynamic_content,
                'success': True
            }
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error('Dynamic crawler exception msg ' + str(ex))
            return {
                'data': None,
                'success': False
            }

    async def close_browser(self):
        if self.browser:
            await self.browser.close()

    async def get_title(self, url):
        async with await self.get_page(url) as page:
            title = await page.title()
        return title


@app.get('/chatbot/dynamic-crawl')
async def chatbot_test(request: Request, url: str = Query(alias='url')):
    return await crawler.get_page(url)

Issue
target page context or browser has been closed
How can I fix this error and ensure that the browser and page context are properly managed? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Once the context managed with block ends, everything is closed. How to start playwright outside 'with' without context managers and can i run playwright outside of 'with'?

Does this answer your question? How to start playwright outside 'with' without context managers
